# Добавить текст в textarea при клике на div

Tags: javascript

Нужно при клике на div добавить текст, расположенный в div'е в textarea. Вот код. Не работает...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('no1').click(function(){  
text = $(this).document.getElementByid('no1').innerHTML;
$('#no').append(' '+text);    
});​
</script>

<div id="no1">Сам текст</div>
<textarea id="no" name="no"></textarea>
```

Comment: append будет добавлять текст, val заменять

Comment: Используя jquery, забудьте про document. В данном случае нужно использвать $(this).text() или $(this).html()



>  $('no1').click(function(){

забыли #

>  $('#no1').click(function(){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто вставит текст:

```
$('#no1').click(function(){  
    $('#no').val($('#no1').text())  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8yyudLbw/

Если же надо добавлять, то:

```
$('#no1').click(function(){  
    $('#no').val($('#no').val() + $('#no1').text())  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8yyudLbw/2/
либо

```
$('#no1').click(function(){  
    $('#no').append($('#no1').text())  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#no1').click(function(){  
  text = $('#no1').text();
  $('#no').append(' ' + text);    
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o0g3g5oa/